# In List Design View, List is disabled

Tags: list-definition, visual-studio-2012

I have two lists that the List toolbar item (Columns/Views/List) is disabled. Attempting to click does nothing.

I've also noticed that when I deploy it, they don't render appropriately. For example, one of the lists is just a title field (lookup for another list. Probably going to scrap that one and use a Choice and just tell the users to maintain accordingly), and renders just a title. That's fine, but if I try to render another list that in the design view has 9 items, it, too, only renders the Title.

How do I find out why the List menu item is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...And it was due to changing the Type number from 10000 to 5502 (read a guide saying you could define template ids here to make the event listeners target that part only).